# Python, beautifulsoup: extract text from table cell

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to extract the table from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Belarusian_citizens) using the following code:

```
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = open('belarus_wiki.txt', 'w')

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Belarusian_citizens"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

country = ""
visa = ""
notes = ""

table = soup.find("table", "sortable wikitable")
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    if len(cells) == 3:
        country = cells[0].findAll(text=True)
        visa = cells[1].findAll(text=True)
        notes = cells[2].find(text=True)

        print country[1].encode("utf-8"), visa[0].encode("utf-8"), notes[0].encode("utf-8")

        file.write(country[1].encode("utf-8") + ',' + visa[0].encode("utf-8") + '\n')

file.close()
```

But I see the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...\belarus_wiki.py", line 27, in <module>
print country[1].encode("utf-8"), visa[0].encode("utf-8"), notes[0].encode("utf-8")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please tell me how to extract all the text from these cells?

Comment: Always include the *full traceback* of any errors you see in Python. That way we don't have to guess where your error lies.

Comment: You should link the parsed page + the full stackstrace.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added a link to the page, and the full text of the traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this :

```
for line in table.findAll('tr'):
    for l in line.findAll('td'):
        if l.find('sup'):
           l.find('sup').extract()
        print l.getText(),'|',
    print
```

Here an extract of what it prints :

```
 Romania | Visa required |  |
 Russia | Freedom of movement |  |
 Rwanda | Visa required | Visa is obtained online. |
 Saint Kitts and Nevis | Visa required | Visa obtainable online. |
 Saint Lucia | Visa required |  |
 Saint Vincent and the Grenadines | Visa not required | 1 month |
 Samoa | Visa on arrival !Entry Permit on arrival | 60 days |
 San Marino | Visa required |  |
 São Tomé and Príncipe | Visa required | Visa is obtained online. |
 Saudi Arabia | Visa required |  |
 Senegal | Visa required |  |
 Serbia | Visa not required | 30 days |
 Seychelles | Visa on arrival !Visitor's Permit on arrival | 1 month |
 Sierra Leone | Visa required |  |
 Singapore | Visa required | May obtain online. |
 Slovakia | Visa required |  |
 Slovenia | Visa required |  |
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But it is not quite what I need. This code extracts from the "visa requirement" column not only the main message, but also a reference number, that I don't need. In the first case I extracted only the first value using visa = cells[1].findAll(text=True) construction. Can you tell me, how should I transform your code to extract only those parts of table cells, that I need?

Comment: Be careful about some values like : Visa on arrival !Visitor's Permit on arrival. Seems that the first value is in "display:none" mode. I don't know is the content is good or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong:**

```
print country[1].encode("utf-8"), visa[0].encode("utf-8"), notes[0].encode("utf-8")
```

**Correct:**

```
if notes is None:
    print country[1].encode("utf-8"), visa[0].encode("utf-8")
else:
    print country[1].encode("utf-8"), visa[0].encode("utf-8"), notes.encode("utf-8")
```

**Complete Code:**

```
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = open('belarus_wiki.txt', 'w')

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Belarusian_citizens"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

country = ""
visa = ""
notes = ""

table = soup.find("table", "sortable wikitable")
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    if len(cells) == 3:
        country = cells[0].findAll(text=True)
        visa = cells[1].findAll(text=True)
        notes = cells[2].find(text=True)
        if notes is None:
            print country[1].encode("utf-8"), visa[0].encode("utf-8")
            file.write(country[1].encode("utf-8") + ',' + visa[0].encode("utf-8") + '\n')
        else:
            print country[1].encode("utf-8"), visa[0].encode("utf-8"), notes.encode("utf-8")
            file.write(country[1].encode("utf-8") + ',' + visa[0].encode("utf-8") + ',' + notes.encode("utf-8") + '\n')
```

**My Environment:**
OS X 10.10.1
Python 2.7.8
BeautifulSoup 4.1.3

Comment: After I corrected code according to this suggestion, I see the following error message: File "...\belarus_wiki.py", line 30, in <module> print country[1].encode("utf-8"), visa[0].encode("utf-8"), notes.encode("utf-8") AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: you also need to fix file.write() line as same as the print line.

Comment: When I corrected "print" and "write" lines of code, I saw the same error message again. But if I use "find" instead of "findAll" in this line: "notes = cells[2].findAll(text=True)", code works, but in several cells there are list of parts of the text and the code extracts only first of them. Please tell me, how can I extract the full text from the table cell.

Comment: In my environment, I don't have the error you saw. I put my code in the answer.

Comment: When I use "find" in this row: `notes = cells[2].find(text=True)`, the code works, but in some cases extracted only part of the text (Ireland for example). The whole text becomes extracted, when I use findAll in the line above, but in this case I see the error message like in my first comment to your answer.